# c++ When i am adding/updating resource, my file gets corrupt

Tags: c++, resources

I am trying to update resource of an exe file bt after adding it when i run that file it show error, xxxx.exe is not a valid win32 application, but i created a valid win32 gui application with a default code to create empty window.

but when i add resource in notepad.exe or calc.exe its working fine.. please help...

```
void export_data::generate(void)
{
    HRSRC hrsrc;
    HGLOBAL hglobal;
    HANDLE hfile, hupdate;
    BOOL temp;
    unsigned long rsize, rsize2;
    unsigned long bytes_written;

    cout << "Generating new file";

    hupdate = BeginUpdateResource("notepad.exe", FALSE);
    if (hupdate == NULL)
        cout << "nError beginupdateresource";

    temp = UpdateResource(hupdate, RT_RCDATA, MAKEINTRESOURCE(10), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL), pbuffer, Filesize);
    if (temp == 0)
        cout << "nupdate resource error 1";

    temp = UpdateResource(hupdate, RT_RCDATA, MAKEINTRESOURCE(20), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL), pPass, pass_size);
    if (temp == 0)
        cout << "nupdate resource error 2";

    cout << "nn" << pPass << "n";
    system("pause");

    temp = EndUpdateResource(hupdate, FALSE);
    if (temp == FALSE)
        cout << "end update error";

    CloseHandle(hupdate);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you actually writing to `notepad.exe` (and not in another file, named `notepad.exe`) and its not get restored from the shadow copy immediately? (because `echo > notepad.exe` fails on Win8 even under administrator privileges)

Comment: yeah i m sure, when i update res in notepad.exe of calc.exe the program i.e calc.exe/notepad.exe runs perfectly and i can read resource later. bt when i try to update resource in a program that i developed, the program gets corrupted and i cant read the res later... @Lol4t0